# Unity 2018 NavmeshBuilder.BuildNavMeshAsync

Tags: unity, c#, navmesh

I am trying to test out the new Navmesh tools as of Unity 2018.1

So i have a simple scene with a plane:

[image]

Then i have the following script:

```
    public class SpawnObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ObjectToSpawn;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
  
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.name == "floor")
                {
                    Instantiate(ObjectToSpawn, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
                    NavMeshBuilder.BuildNavMeshAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This spawns a prefab and then i attempt to update the navmesh however nothing really happens:

[image]

The cube I am spawning has the following properties:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your object is not marked as nav mesh static and is not a nav mesh obstacle.

Either change the static flags on the prefab (press the down arrow next to the “static” checkbox) or add a nav mesh obstacle component.